# Rotating the text in the pie chart of d3.js and alternate filling of colors

Tags: d3.js

I have this d3 code for drawing the pie chart in d3.js

```
/** START OF PIE CHART */

        var svgCirWidth = 600, svgCirHeight = 300, radius = Math.min(svgCirWidth, svgCirHeight) / 2;

        const pieContainer = d3.select("#pieChart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", svgCirWidth)
            .attr("height", svgCirHeight);

        //create group element to hold pie chart

        var g = pieContainer.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 250 + "," + radius + ")");

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

        var pie = d3.pie().value(function (d) {
            return d.total_up_percentage;
        });

        var path = d3.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius)
            .innerRadius(0);

        var arc = g.selectAll("arc")
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter() //means keeps looping in the data
            .append("g");

        arc.append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d.data.total_up_percentage);
            })
            .append("text")
            .text("afdaf");

        var label = d3.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius)
            .innerRadius(0);

        arc.append("text")
            .attr("transform", (d) => {
                return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")";
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text((d) => {
                return d.data.region_iso_code + ":" + d.data.total_up_percentage + "%"
            });
```

and this is the result of my pie

[image: piechart]

as you can see the text overlaps each other. I was wondering how can i rotate the text so it can be much more easier to read. I've tried editing the transform in the console but it won't work it just makes the text go up or down. Also I was wondering what happened to the color of my pie. It stuck on orange. It says on the documentation i read about this `schemeCategory10` is that it is a 10 color code scheme. Yet it won't show the rest of the color. Is there any other way to change color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an ordinal scale you should never rely on the scale's ability to infer the domain from usage: a good practice is always to explicitly set the domain.

By setting the domain you'd quickly see that this is indeed the expected behaviour: all orange slices have the same value, which is `100`.

If you want different colors for those **same** values, use the indices instead:

```
.attr("fill", function (_, i) {
    return color(i);
})
```

---

PS: regarding the texts, please avoid asking 2 or more different issues in a single question. Edit your question leaving just 1 issue, you can always post a new question with the other issues.